# A Measure Theoretic Approach to Probability

Tags: probability, measure-theory, reference-request

I know the standard semester or two of measure theory. But I have never looked into probability past the sections in measure theory books.

Is there a book that covers basic probability (a standard semester or two at the graduate level) that assumes measure theory. Also, how much more probability at this level is there?

Comment: You want any graduate probability text like Shiryaev.

Comment: Yes, this is what pretty much every graduate-level probability book does; or else its first few chapters cover measure theory, and you can just skim them to understand the notation.

Answer (score 2):

A popular book that covers a lot of material is Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples book. He doesn't "assume" you know measure theory since he reviews it very quickly, but after that point, he assumes you know measure theory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the most canonical text for probability at the measure theoretic level is *Probability and Measure* by Billingsley

[Billingsley](http://www.colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/billingsley.pdf)

Beyond basic probability, there is also the standard (primarily reference) text *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus* by Karatzas and Shreve

[Karatzas and Shreve](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-0949-2)

I also like the 2 volume series *Diffusions, Markov Processes and Martingales* by Rogers and Williams

[Rogers and Williams](https://books.google.com/books/about/Diffusions_Markov_Processes_and_Martinga.html?id=eJp330pIvQ4C)